# CakePHP 4 - customising the query used by the Authentication component

Tags: php, cakephp

On a CakePHP 4.3.5 website I'm using the Authentication and Authorization components mentioned in the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html):

- [Authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html)
- [Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/index.html)

These supersede the old AuthComponent that was used in previous versions of CakePHP. This is mentioned in the docs:

> Deprecated since version 4.0.0: The AuthComponent is deprecated as of 4.0.0 and will be replaced by the authorization and authentication plugins.

My question is related to the new Authentication component. I want to customise the query that I use when a user attempts to login.

I have 2 columns in my `users` table called `email_verified` and `banned`. By default in my application both of these fields are `NULL` in the database. So when a user creates an account both of these have `NULL` values. If/when a user verifies their email address, `email_verified` gets updated to a `tinyint(1)` with a value `1`. The `banned` field remains `NULL` unless the user gets banned by an administrator, at which point it would also be updated to `1`.

Thus I want my login query to find Users where `email_verified => 1` and `banned => NULL`.

In the documentation - for what I assume is the "old" AuthComponent way of doing things - it has an [example](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query). The only difference in the example is that the query looks at a database column called `active` however I'm comfortable with how to change that to use the 2 columns I've mentioned above.

The problem is that this doesn't work and I assume it's because the new components work differently. There seems to be a lack of documentation about how to get it to work.

What I tried was as follows:

```
// src/Controller/AppController.php
public function initialize(): void
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Authorization.Authorization', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'finder' => 'auth'
    ]
    // ...
}
```

I then added a method to my `UsersTable.php` model file as per the documentation, substituting the appropriate fields:

```
// src/Model/Table/UsersTable.php
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(['id', 'email', 'password', 'email_verified', 'banned'])
        ->where(['Users.email_verified' => 1, 'Users.banned' => null]);

    return $query;
}
```

This doesn't work. Any user - with the correct username/password combination - can login, irrespective of the values of `email_verified` or `banned`. I even tried changing these to non-existent columns (e.g. `Users.email_verified_foo_bar_baz`) to see if it errored. It doesn't error and I don't think it's even using this function.

How can I get this to work with the new Authorization component in CakePHP 4?

Comment: You must implement the finder in the identifier, not in the component. https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identifiers.html